# jquery: How do I find all the class names and number of instances of a element

Tags: jquery, class, indexing, mouse, unique

I have created a set of divs of different size that all reside within a parent. These divs have different class names depending on their size and content. What they share is another classname called EditBlock. The code for making the divs is ....

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function makeSmallBlockdiv ()
{
var smallBlock = $('<div class="SmallBlock EditBlock"></div>').appendTo("#canvas");
smallBlock.draggable({containment: "#canvas", scroll: false, grid: [10, 10]}, {cursor: "move", cursorAt: {top: 125, left: 150}})
smallBlock.append('<div class="article_title fontCenter fontBold font24">Article Title</div>')
smallBlock.append('<div class="article_Image"><img style="width: 250px;" src="<? echo $image1 ?>"></div>')
smallBlock.append('<div class="font14"><? echo substr($article_text, 0, 200) ?></div>') 

}

</script>
```

A second div is as follows ..

```
<!-- script to create large block draggable div  -->  

<script type="text/javascript">
function makeLargeBlockdiv ()
{
var largeBlock = $('<div class="LargeBlock EditBlock"></div>').appendTo("#canvas");
largeBlock.draggable({containment: "#canvas", scroll: false, grid: [10, 10]}, {cursor: "move", cursorAt: {top: 250, left: 210}})
largeBlock.append('<div class="article_title fontCenter fontBold font32">Article Title</div>')
largeBlock.append('<div class="article_Image"><img style="width: 90%" src="<? echo $image ?>"></div>')

largeBlock.append('<div class="font14"><? echo substr($article_text, 0, 200) ?></div>') 

}    
</script>
```

The problem I am having is that I need to identify which div has the mouse over it.  Since there can be multiple instances of thres divs, I also need to find the correct index of that div.

This is the code I am using to identify the div, but I don't know how to get the index and unique classname.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.EditBlock').bind('mouseover mouseout click', function(event) {
        var $tgt = $(event.target);
        if (!$tgt.closest('.syntax_hilite').length) {
          $tgt.toggleClass(event.type == 'click' ? 'outline-element-clicked' : 'outline-element');      
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

To recap, I need to get the classname for the div and the index that is associated with the instance of the div.

Sorry for being so long winded but I couldn't explain it in fewer words.

I forgot to mention that I am just starting to learn jquery and ill be asking more questions in the comming day.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be creating the `div's dynamically` . So you need to attach the events using **Event delegation.**

```
$('.EditBlock').bind('mouseover mouseout click', function(event) {
```

Should be

```
$('body').on('mouseover mouseout click','.EditBlock', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    //Then to access the **classNames** you can do this

    var classNames[] = $this.attr('class').split(' ');

   // To access the index of the current div..

   var index = $this.index();

});
```

**UPDATED**

Try this

```
​$('#small , #big').on('click', function(){
    var $container = $('#container');
    if(this.id === 'small'){
          $container.append('<div class="smallBlock EditBlock">' +
                              'Small Block </div>');
    }
    else{
          $container.append('<div class="largeBlock EditBlock">' +
                              'Large Block </div>');
    }        
});

$('#container').on('click','.EditBlock', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $container = $('#container');
    //Then to access the **classNames** you can do this
    var index;
    if($this.hasClass('smallBlock')){
       index = $container.find('.smallBlock').index($this);
        alert('Current Small Block index is : ' + index);        
    }
    else if ($this.hasClass('largeBlock')){
        index = $container.find('.largeBlock').index($this);
        alert('Current Large Block index is : ' + index);         
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/beR6r/)**

Comment: I changed the code to what you suggested and it works, but how do I get the unique classname and index?

Comment: sorry, i am brand new to jquery, what do you mean by .on

Comment: He meant you need to use .on()  instead of .bind()  ..  It's the new way of attaching events from version 1.7.0

Comment: there is a generic class name called EditBlock that is associated with all the divs, but I also have class names that describe the type of div; large small etc.  Since I can have more than one div of the same type, I need to find out which class I selected and which copy of that div is highlited.  Look at the first two blocks of code, You can see that there are classes called SmallBlock and LargeBlock.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the rest of the code you put up.  I am going to put it in now, but can you tell me how to to keep my element highliting section?

Comment: Does classnames[] contain all the class names of the selected div?

Comment: It it contains the array of all the classes the particular div has

Comment: I just printed it out with writeln and nothing appeared. I only get a "}".

Comment: Loking now, I am going through it on fiddle.  I am new to jquery  so it will take me a bit of time. I see your code works, I just need to integrate it with my original element highliting code.

Comment: I just put this code into my project and it didn't fire.  Is it important where I place the code?

Comment: It is not important where you place the code if it's inside Document.ready handler.. Also its a better idea to attach the events in js file rather than using inline javascirpt